# Speed optimisation in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

My project (Python 2.7) consists of a screen scraper that collects data once a day, extracts what is useful and stores that in a couple of pickles. The pickles are rendered to an HTML-page using Flask/Ninja. All that works, but when running it on my localhost (Windows 10), it's rather slow. I plan to deploy it on PythonAnywhere.

The site also has an about page. Content for the about page is a markdown file, that I convert to HTML using `markdown2` after each edit. The about-template loads the HTML, like so:

```
{% include 'about_content.html' %}
```

This loads *much* faster than letting `Flask-Markdown` render the about-text (as I had at first):

```
{% filter markdown %}
{% include 'about_content.md' %}
{% endfilter %}
```

Now then. I'm a bit worried that the main page will not load fast enough when I deploy the site. The content gets updated only once a day, there is no need to re-render anything if you refresh the main page. So I'm wondering if I can do a similar trick as with the about-content:

Can I let Flask, after rendering the pickles, save the result as html, and then serve that from the site deployed? Or can I invoke some browser module, save its output, and serve that? Or is that a bad idea altogether, and shouldn't I worry because Flask is zoomingly fast on real life servers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Your Question on Rendering

You can actually do a lot with Jinja. It is possible to run Jinja whenever you want and save it as a HTML file. This way every time you send a request for a file, it doesn't have to render it again. It just serves the static file.

Here is some code. I have a view that doesn't change throughout it's lifetime. So I create a static HTML file once the view is created.

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

def example_function():
    '''Jinja templates are used to write to a new file instead of rendering when a request is received. Run this function whenever you need to create a static file'''

    # I tell Jinja to use the templates directory
    env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'))
    
    # Look for the results template
    template = env.get_template('results.html')

    # You just render it once. Pass in whatever values you need. 
    # I'll only be changing the title in this small example.
    output_from_parsed_template = template.render(title="Results")

    with open("/directory/where/you/want/to/save/index.html", 'w') as f:
        f.write(output_from_parsed_template)

# Flask route
@app.route('/directory/where/you/want/to/save/<path:path>')
def serve_static_file(path):
    return send_from_directory("directory/where/you/want/to/save/", path)
```

Now if you go the above URI `localhost:5000/directory/where/you/want/to/save/index.html` is served without rendering.

**EDIT** Note that `@app.route` takes a URL, so `/directory/where/you/want/to/save` must start at the root, otherwise you get `ValueError: urls must start with a leading slash`. Also, you can save the rendered page with the other templates, and then route it as below, eliminating the need for (and it's just as fast as) `send_from_directory`:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

### Other Ways

If you want to get better performance consider serving your Flask app via *gunicorn, nginx and the likes.*

[Setting up nginx, gunicorn and  Flask](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)

[Don't use Flask built-in server in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086555/why-shouldnt-flask-be-deployed-with-the-built-in-server)

Flask also has an option where you can enable multi threading.

```
app.run(threaded=True)
```

### Updates on 11th Nov, 2018

- You can consider using a Redis store. Everytime something happens that invalidates the old template, clear the cache for the particular file. First look into the Redis store before generating the template again (template rendering will most likely require you to read from a database for data. In-memory cache stores are much faster, so you stand to benefit from a Redis cache)
- Store the rendered file and serve using a CDN. So everytime a client requests for that particular template it will already be stored on the CDN and will not touch your Flask server at all. You can write logic such that if the file or content doesn't exist on the CDN, it should fallback to your Flask server. You just need to ensure a strategy so that you don't have stale data on the CDN.

Comment: By the way I forgot to mention. Never use Flask on real servers (production). The creator of Flask himself is against the idea. Flask isn't secure nor is it efficient in real life situations. Use gunicorn and nginx along side Flask if you want to deploy it on production.

Comment: A quick note from a PythonAnywhere dev (as the OP said they were planning to deploy on our site) -- we use nginx as our front-end web server, so your Flask app is secure and efficient.

Comment: @RolfBly that should reduce your work. Using gunicorn just requires 3 to 4 lines of additional code. You should also know that gunicorn doesn't work on windows (it only works on unix). You can directly use it while deploying it on PythonAnywhere.

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal Many thanks! I got it working as desired (see edit). I did struggle a bit with your `app.route`. I guess I need to read up on decorators and the `<path:path>` trick.

Comment: @RolfBly Please note that you must use send_from_directory to send the file. Don't use render_template. Why to waste time (it would open the file and search for Jinja markup and then send it) when we already know it's rendered. Sorry for the typo. I fixed my answer :)

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal I accept your point that rendering it would theoretically take longer, but there's nothing to do for Jinja. I didn't notice any difference in speed. I chose this because a relative path makes the whole thing more portable. But, if there are truly prohibitive arguments against render_template, please share.

Comment: If you use render template, Jinja will go through the HTML (and find nothing to render) before sending it. (It doesn't know it's already rendered). Of course it's much faster than a page that isn't rendered but slower than send_from_directory.

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal Thanks once again! Just to wrap up: I'm still using render_template, but I now load the rendered table into a separate index template. So I can (1) still use the relative path, (2) have some flexibility to elements to the index template later, and (3) still have quite acceptable speed.

Comment: Okay. All the best. If it works without any hiccups, it's good. Optimise it in the future if you have any problems scaling it up :)