# Is it possible to terminate a Flask worker process after processing N requests?

Tags: python, flask, python-multiprocessing

If I am using the `processes` parameter (`application.run(processes=10)`) in Flask is it possible to specify somehow to terminate the process after it handles N tasks ?

Basically I would like to reuse a resource for N requests then recreate it after N calls by killing the current process and forcing flask to replace it with a new process. The functionality would be similar to using `multiprocessing.Pool` with a `maxtasksperchild` parameter equal to N.

Comment: Looks like flask creates a new process for every request. So first I need to find out how to make it reuse an old process at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the Flask dev server in any situation where killing processes after N requests would be relevant. [Use a real WSGI server in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086555/why-shouldnt-flask-be-deployed-with-the-built-in-server/33088612#33088612), they all have options for this.

For example, with [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/):

```
gunicorn --max-requests=N --workers=10 myapp:app
```